# Can't rename files when uploaded with php-uploader

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use php-uploader (https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader) library and I want it to save custom names while it uploads images. How to make [replaced] field correctly get the new name?

Below is a response i'm getting.

Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => /var/2/17xxxxxx/bat1.jpg
            [1] => /var//2/17xxxxxx/bat2.jpg
        )

```
[metas] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => Mon, 03 Oct 2016 21:00:37 +0200
                [extension] => jpg
                [file] => /var/2/17xxxxxx/bat1.jpg
                [name] => bat1.jpg
                [old_name] => bat1.jpg
                [replaced] => 
                [size] => 1029224
                [size2] => 1,005.10 KB
                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => image
                        [1] => jpeg
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => Mon, 03 Oct 2016 21:00:37 +0200
                [extension] => jpg
                [file] => /var/2/17xxxxxx/bat2.jpg
                [name] => bat2.jpg
                [old_name] => bat2.jpg
                [replaced] => 
                [size] => 573283
                [size2] => 559.85 KB
                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => image
                        [1] => jpeg
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1):

if you look in the php-uploader docs there is a "title" option, using it you can set the new filename